# Do gerim say the section for the nasi at the end of shachris during nissan?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, korban, shevatim-12-tribes, mishkan-tabernacle

Some have a [custom to say the Nassi](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/495713/jewish/The-Nasi.htm) after Shacharis during the first 12 or 13 days of Nissan. At the end of the recital of a passage from Chumash deliniating each tribal leader's contribution offered on that day of Nissan when the Mishkan was first built. There is a prayer that says in part "if I am from the tribe of ..." and each day the tribe that is mentioned in the portion of Chumash said.

Does someone who is a convert, and thus knows positively that he is not from any of those tribes, say some or all of this (either the Chumash or the subsequent prayer)?

Comment: According to Rambam they says mikra Bikurim, they says , Elokey avotenu, See mishnayot bikurim 1, 4 in mefarshim

Comment: See Mishna Bikurim 1, 4.<br>
See Tosfot Yom Tov [here](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37940&st=&pgnum=333&hilite=) in name of Rambam (See tshuvot Harambam). May be that the words are said in name of Clalut Israel.
I am not sure so it is a comment and not an answer

Comment: how about a Levi who knows he is not from any of those tribes?